# Apache ignite disk compression not working on windows

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I am trying to user apache ignite disk compression on windows for a cache with disk persistence ON
but it fails with below error -

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Currently page compression is supported only for Linux.
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.compress.CompressionProcessorImpl.checkPageCompressionSupported(CompressionProcessorImpl.java:76)

I am following steps mentioned on the page -
[https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/disk-compression#:~:text=Disk%20compression%20refers%20to%20the,compressed%20using%20the%20configured%20algorithm](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/disk-compression#:%7E:text=Disk%20compression%20refers%20to%20the,compressed%20using%20the%20configured%20algorithm).

No where in the ignite documentation says that it is NOT supported on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would believe the error message. It’s pretty clear and explicit. Maybe you can leave some feedback on the documentation (there’s a button on the bottom right of each page).